# Bootstrap Responsive Navbar is showing but collapsed at any resolution in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing and intranet web application using ASP.NET for my company. this application will only run locally.

I am using Bootstrap 3.

the navigation bar works fine on IE9 and above. But when I test it on IE8, it shows as collapse (showing the burger menu instead of regular menu). Doesn't matter how i re-size the browser, the burger menu is there.

I have already did all the recommended steps by Bootstrap and I am using Response.js

I even built a sample site just using a template from Bootstrap and I downloaded ALL the files locally in the website. still, same problem.

here is the sample:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>



    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

what am I doing wrong here?

does it have anything to do with me being behind a firewall in my company?

Comment: not related to my problem. it is asking about Bootstrap 2 and I am asking about 3. Also he has a different problem than mine

Comment: Then post your code? Or give us a fiddle/codepen/etc that would accurately replicate the problem.

Comment: sure .. i will post the sample code that i tried. waiting for your help. seems you're an expert :)

Comment: Not an expert, just better ways to ask for help is all: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks for the info. i posted the test code. hopefully someone will answer it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For media query support in IE8 you need to use Respond.js which will allow media queries to work.

Repo: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Comment: thanks for response Glen. However, if you read my post, I have already included Respond in my page and all files are local.

Comment: Are you sure you have followed the instructions as laid out on Respond JS? You need to make sure that the RespondJS is called AFTER your CSS is loaded. Closer the better.

Comment: MAN !!! OMG ! you're a star !!! how could I have missed that ! I seriously don't know how to thank you. you just saved my project :) ..

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 is "mobile first", which means that the "mobile" layout is the default layout with no media queries applied. As the screen gets larger media queries are applied to modify the layout for those sizes.

IE8 that doesn't support mediaqueries will always show the mobile layout. This is what is expected when using Bootstrap 3 in IE8.

Comment: Bootstrap supports IE8+. And with the help on Respond.js you should be fine displaying the website on IE8. My problem is that Respond.js is not working for me and the menu is showing as a mobile menu

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not running it locally. coz respond.js will not work if you are running it locally on the browser.  like file://something/nameofthefile

run it in a localhost or on a ftp server